# Wordpress search doesn't work on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to make search work on button click on opening of popup using below jQuery code

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#secondaryButton').click(function() {
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    $("button.elementor-search-form__submit").click();
  });
});
```

I have tried adding script code in header.php it doesn't work
I also tried adding script code in custom js on page level using elementor pro plugin, it doesn't work

I am not sure why scripting doesn't work. The link which i am working is

https://adelaidebuildingconsulting.com.au/

Once you click search icon, a popup will open and i am looking to implement search on 'search' button click. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues in your code. Firstly the right-side panel which contains the `#secondaryButton` element doesn't exist in the DOM when the page loads, so you need to use a delegated event handler.

Secondly, you need to invoke the `click()` method on the `button` element directly, not through jQuery. To do that use `[0]` to retrieve the Element from the jQuery object:

```
$("button.elementor-search-form__submit")[0].click();
```

However, in this case better practice to submit the `form` element would be to invoke the `submit` event on that element, not the click of its button:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '#secondaryButton', e => {
    $("form.elementor-search-form")[0].submit();
  });
});
```

That being said, the best practice would be to completely remove the need for any JS hacks to form a relationship between your `form` and an external submit button. If you rearrange your HTML so that the clickable 'Search' element is a `<button />` element within the `form` then you get the behaviour you require by default, without the need for any JS.

Comment: Hi Rory. Thanks for your answer. Actually, the search functionality is the default for wordpress. I am not sure how to modify the form of the search. :(